# CouchDB templating system: extend with separate footer & header

Tags: html, templates, couchdb, couchapp

I'm using couchdb\couchapp to host a web application. 
I comes from Django, and with jinja2 I'm able to extend templates in two ways:

{% include "header.html" %}

or

{% extends "base.html" %} <<<---- preferred

I'm looking for a way to do the same with CouchDB, now I have header and footer code written in every single page and, obv, it doesn't look as best practice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I managed it concatenating the templates 'header' 'body and 'footer' from a show function with a simple js.

Answer (score 1):

Couch db [supports common js modules](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CommonJS_Modules) which means that you can export the mustache/or other templating  library as a string and then require it in your show function. More explanation on this [mail archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@couchdb.apache.org/msg17539.html)

> If you want to use JavaScript on the server side, you'll need to store it as a 
>   *property* on your design doc. So in a "lib" folder (outside of _attachments) 
>   with the 'couchapp' it will get included like:
>
> couchapp folder
>
> _id file
>
> |_ _attachments folder
>
> ```
> |_ ...clientside media...
> ```
>
> |_ lib folder
>
> |_ mustache.js
>
> <---->
>
> {_id:"", _attachments: {...}, lib:{mustache:""}}
>
> Then you would use it in a _show/_list/_update function with `var Mustache = 
>   require('lib/mustache')`. When I do need a library both server and clientside 
>   with 'couchapp', I tend to symlink it so it appears in both _attachments and 
>   other properties.
>
> hope this helps,
>
> -natevw